# Type mismatch in Kotlin when using strategy pattern with generics

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I need to implement a backend system which accepts multiple payment methods, and then process them according to their type.

I used Strategy Pattern, but I can't seem to make it work when I initialize the service because of Type Mismatch.
I'm probably missing or misunderstanding something with the Generics in kotlin.

```
 val gateways =
        listOf(
            CreditGateway(),
            PayPalGateway()
        )
 val api = PaymentAPI(gateways) <-- error: Type mismatch 
 api.authorizeFunds(PayPalModel(...))

 Required:
 List<IPaymentService<IPaymentModel>>
 Found:
 List<IPaymentService<{CreditModel & PayPalModel}>>
```

The code implementation is:

```
interface IPaymentModel

class CreditModel : IPaymentModel
class PayPalModel : IPaymentModel

interface IPaymentService<in T> where T: IPaymentModel {
    suspend fun authorizeFunds(model: T)
    suspend fun appliesTo(type: IPaymentModel): Boolean
}

class CreditGateway : IPaymentService<CreditModel> {
    override suspend fun authorizeFunds(model: CreditModel) {
      /// implementation
    }
    override suspend fun appliesTo(type: IPaymentModel): Boolean {
        return type is CreditModel
    }
}

class PayPalGateway : IPaymentService<PayPalModel> {
    override suspend fun authorizeFunds(model: PayPalModel) {
      /// implementation
    }
    override suspend fun appliesTo(type: IPaymentModel): Boolean {
        return type is PayPalModel
    }
}

interface IPaymentStrategy<T: IPaymentService<IPaymentModel>> {
    suspend fun <T: IPaymentModel> authorizeFunds(model: T)
}

class PaymentAPI(
    private val paymentServices: List<IPaymentService<IPaymentModel>>
): IPaymentStrategy<IPaymentModel> {

    override suspend fun <T : IPaymentModel> authorizeFunds(model: T) {
        findService(model)?.authorizeFunds(model)
    }
    
    private fun <T : IPaymentModel> findService(model: T) ????
}
```

Comment: This design is inherently flawed. What if I do `paymentServices[0]. authorizeFunds(somePaypalModel)`? From the type system's perspective, I should be able to do this. `paymentServices[0]` is a `IPaymentService<IPaymentModel>`, so I can pass any `IPaymentModel` to `authorizeFunds`. However, in actuality, `paymentServices[0]` is a `CreditGateway`, which can only take `CreditModel`s.

Comment: And it doesn't make sense for `PaymentAPI` to implement `IPaymentStrategy<IPaymentModel>`. `IPaymentStrategy<T>` requires `T` to be a payment *service*, not a payment model.

Comment: Is the whole strategy pattern irrelevant for this usecase, or would you recommend making certain adjustments?
Regarding the paymentServices[0] that's what the "findService" was for, but I understand what you mean... I just didn't have a better idea how to refactor it properly otherwise

Comment: It ***is*** relevant. `IPaymentStrategy<IPaymentModel>` is an invalid type. Do you want me to assume that `PaymentAPI` doesn't implement any interface then? `findService` can't check the generic arguments of payment services, because of type erasure. It can only determine whether a payment service is applicable using other means, like `appliesTo` (but that would require `findService` to suspend), or some other property in `IPaymentService`.

Comment: but since PaymentAPI is intended to obstruct the internal Service/gateways available, so one could just pass it the PaymentModel to it and it would locate and select the service itself, if I change its implementation to IPaymentStrategy<IPaymentService> it would not allow me to pass the Payment model, it would require passing a service.. Or am I missing here something?

Comment: Well then its declaration is incorrect. It should just be `interface IPaymentStrategy<T: IPaymentModel>`, and `authorizeFunds` doesn't need to be generic. By the way, if you think something is irrelevant, *don't include it in your question*, and don't complain when answers don't take that thing into account.

Comment: I didn't complain, I just wondered in my first message whether my approach was irrelevant (= wrong) to begin with for this problem.
Regarding your suggestion, I changed to `interface IPaymentStrategy<T: IPaymentModel> {
    suspend fun authorizeFunds(model: T)
}`, but it doesn't help with the initial compile error.
I'm thinking how can I go about it so I can have the benefits of strategy pattern here, but also taking into account your important remarks ?

Comment: I see what you mean by "irrelevant" now. Your approach could very well be wrong. You could very well be using the strategy pattern for its own sake (when you only have a hammer, everything looks like a nail). And I didn't say that would fix the error.

Comment: I see.. can you say how would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `IPaymentStrategy<IPaymentModel>` is not a valid type. `IPaymentStrategy<T>` requires `T` to be a `IPaymentService`, not an `IPaymentModel`. If you want this to be valid, then `IPaymentStrategy` should be declared like this:

```
interface IPaymentStrategy<in T: IPaymentModel> {
    // authorizeFunds should not be generic
    suspend fun authorizeFunds(model: T)
}
```

Note that if all the strategies you are going to write are `IPaymentStrategy<IPaymentModel>`s, it doesn't need to be generic.

Second, you need to find a way to determine whether a payment service is applicable to a given `IPaymentModel`, so that you can find a suitable service in `findService`. You cannot directly check its type parameter, because of type erasure. You could use `appliesTo`, which would require `findService` to suspend, because `appliesTo` suspends. Alternatively, add some other property to `IPaymentService` that you can check.

With that out of the way, you can now write `PaymentAPI`. The type of `paymentServices` should be `List<IPaymentService<*>>` so that you can have a heterogeneous list of services.

```
class PaymentAPI(
    private val paymentServices: List<IPaymentService<*>>
): IPaymentStrategy<IPaymentModel>
```

Now `PaymentAPI(gateways)` would compile.

For `findService`, you can implement it like this:

```
private suspend fun findService(model: IPaymentModel): IPaymentService<IPaymentModel>? {
    for (service in paymentServices) {
        if (service.appliesTo(model)) {
            return service as IPaymentService<IPaymentModel>
        }
    }
    return null
}

override suspend fun authorizeFunds(model: IPaymentModel) {
    findService(model)?.authorizeFunds(model)
}
```

The unchecked cast `as IPaymentService<IPaymentModel>` is necessary because of type erasure. If you accidentally cast to a payment service that doesn't take that type of model, it would throw an exception at `findService(model)?.authorizeFunds(model)`.

The strategy pattern might well be over-complicating this, but I cannot say for sure without looking at the bigger picture.

Comment: I see now what you meant, thank you.
Small question about the payment model :
What if we don't need it? Example : If the Client uses some "stripe sdk" and upon placing an order to the server, they're just passing (1) payment method selected + (2) auth_id (received from the sdk in client), then it means that the PaymentModel is somewhat redundant, right? because they'll all hold the same data.  However, if we generalize the PaymentModel, the Generics IPaymentModel would lose its "ability" to distinguish between the services. Could this be handled ?

Comment: @BVtp Not sure what you mean, but I think that could be its own question. I suggest posting a new question and include more details.